# How to retrieve the PendingIntent in the NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, notification-listener

I created a `NotificationListenerService` to play a sound once a I receive PUSH notification. But the `NotificationListenerService` informs me about any Notification occured system-wide, and 
what i am trying to do is, to restrict the behaviour of the `NotificationListenerService` so that to respond to notifications posted from my App only. In other words, the callback `onNotificationPostedPosted`
in the below posted code in `NLS` section, is getting called even if I plug the USB cable to the device and the code in that callback executes, and I want the code in
`onNotificationPostedPosted' to be executed only when my App send a notification.

To solve this issue, as shown in the code below, I added extra to my `Intent` as follows:

```
intent.putExtra("key_message", "MANT-App");
```

The problem I have no is, that I can not have access to that intent in `onNotificationPostedPosted'.

Please let me know how to get/access the `Intent`or the `PendingIntent` in `onNotificationPostedPosted'?

**code**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity_.class);
    intent.putExtra("key_message", "MANT-App");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg)).setContentText(msg).setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent).setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLights(Color.argb(1, 255, 0, 0), 400, 1300);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

**NLS**

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    Log.w(TAG, "onNotificationPosted");

    Log.d(TAG, "sbn.describeContents(): " + sbn.describeContents());
    Log.d(TAG, "getNotification().contentIntent.describeContents(): " + sbn.getNotification().contentIntent.describeContents());

    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.obj = "onNotificationPosted";
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    mNotificationRemoved = false;
    if (!NLSNotificationTone11.TONE_IS_PLAYING) {
        NLSNotificationTone11.TONE_IS_PLAYING = true;
        new ThreadPlayTone(this, NLSNotificationTone11.DURATION_OF_RING_TONE).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = statusBarNotification.getNotification().contentIntent
```

use this method to get PendingIntent for API level 18 & Higher in NotificationListener Class

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know how to get/access the `Intent` or the `PendingIntent` in
>   `onNotificationPosted()`?

You can't. You can send the PendingIntent, but you cannot examine it.

However, you can get the package name of the package posting the `Notification`, so that would be a way to ignore all notifications except ones from your own app.

In `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)`:

```
if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("my.package.name")) {
    // do stuff
}
```

**EDIT: It looks like you can get the `Intent` from a `PendingIntent` using reflection starting with Android 4.2.2.** Do it like this:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = ... // PendingIntent
    try {
        Method method = PendingIntent.class.getDeclaredMethod("getIntent");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Intent intent = method.invoke(pendingIntent);
        // Here you should have the Intent that is wrapped by the PendingIntent.
        //  You should be able to access the component name, extras,
        //  flags, etc. in the Intent
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Problem using reflection
    }
```